# How do popups in HTML work and how can I make this one work?

Tags: html, popup

I copied and pasted most of this code from various examples I found online, but I don't really know how it works, so I'm having trouble debugging it. I want the submit button to also trigger the popup, so that whenever someone submits, they get the warning first, however, I can't see how to do that because I have no clue how the popups actually work. Thank you :)

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="2.css"/>
    <script>
        function togglePopup(){
document.getElementById("popup-1").classList.toggle("active");
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form>
        <h3>Please insert your position on the Political Compass based upon the image.</h3>
        <section id="y">
            <label for="y-position">Y Position:</label>
            <input id="y-position" type="number" step="1" name="y-position" min="-10" max="10" maxlength="2">
        </section>
        <section id="x">
            <label for="x-position">X Position:</label>
            <input id="x-position" type="number" step="1" name="x-position" min="-10" max="10" maxlength="2">
        </section>
        <section id="image">
        <figure>
            <img src="path to image">
        </figure>
        </section>
        <div class="popup" id="popup-1">
            <div class="overlay" style="position: fixed; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 100vw; height: 100vh; background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7); z-index: 1; display: none;"></div>
            <div class="content" style="position: absolute; top: 50%; left: 50%; transform: translate(-50%,-50%) scale(0); background: #fff; width: 450px; height: 220px; z-index: 2; text-align: center; padding: 20px; box-sizing: border-box;">
                <div class="close-btn" onclick="togglePopup()" style="cursor: pointer; position: absolute; right: 20px; top: 20px; width: 30px; height: 30px; background: #222; color: #fff; font-size: 25px; font-weight: 600; line-height: 30px; text-align: center; border-radius: 50%;">&times;</div>
                <h1>Warning</h1>
                <p>You have been warned.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <button onclick="togglePopup()" type="submit" value="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
</body>
```

Answer (score -1):

This is how it works:
https://codepen.io/aalainn/pen/yLPEKNy

What I did:

Cleaned up your code a bit.

Moved all inline-styles into the style-tag as classes.

Added `display: none;` to the class `.popup` of the popup-element.

Added class `.active` with property `display: block;`

Removed `display: none;` from class `.overlay` of the overlay-element.

Removed `scale(0)` from transform-propert in the class `.content`.

Added `e.preventDefault();` to the function `togglePopup()` to prevent reloading the page.